# How to use getElementsByClass syntax in jsoup for multiple records?

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to extract items such as ticket number and prize amount on the website: http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/federal/

Looking at the HTML, ticket items and prize values ​​appear as several records:  `<td class =" ng-binding "> 'ticket' or 'prize amount' </td>`

I used the following syntax, but without success:

```
Elements ticket1 = document.getElementsByClass (". Ng-binding");
```

So how can I get these values?

Comment: The class name is "ng-binding" not ". Ng-binding". If you are using chrome, open the developer console (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `J`) and test it there: `document.getElementsByClassName("ng-binding")`

Comment: You are trying to fetch a value stored in an Angular variable. Jsoup can't do that and the webmaster stored in variables for a reason...